# How can i avoid specific chars with patterns

Tags: html, primefaces, customvalidator, custom-validators

I have to validate an input text: through the client side, the user can insert &,# and @ but not other type of special chars.
I'm using PrimeFaces and i have tried so:
`<f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z@&#]+|+!+\+/+*+%+£+$" />`
but it doesn't works. How can i do?

Comment: What about `<f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z&@#]+" />`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this online regex validator for testing:

https://regex101.com/

I'm not a regex expert but I think you need to use an escape character with some of your characters

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex is not correct.

I suggest to check out this website where you can live test your regex: http://www.regexr.com/

If you submit `^[a-zA-Z@&#]+|+!+\+/+*+%+£+$` you will notice that you do not match any characters so I'd suggest to use this one instead `[a-zA-Z&@#]+` which seems to match your needs.